# Setting Named Range on Specific Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have se up a script to generate a copy of a sheet. I would like to then in the same script create named ranges using for the created sheet so that I can utilize them later to take data out of the ranges. I am running into the problem that it will only let me create a named range for the active sheet and not a specific sheet. Is this possible? here is what I tried so far:

```
function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const  templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Traditional Sheet");
var sheetName = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName("F"+sheetName);
var ods = ss.getSheetByName("F"+sheetName);
var bn = ods.getRange("D1").getValue()
  var nameBD1 = bn+"BD1"
  ss.setNamedRange(nameBD1,"F"+sheetName+"!A1");
}
```

```
function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const  templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Traditional Sheet");
var sheetName = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName("F"+sheetName);
var bn = ods.getRange("D1").getValue()
var ods = ss.getSheetByName("F"+sheetName);
ods.setNamedRange(bn+"BD1",ods.getRange("A1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setNamedRange will work for any range on any sheet as far as I can tell.

```
function myFunck() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("AnySheet");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A2:J11");
  ss.setNamedRange("AnySheet",rg);
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Spreadsheet.setNamedRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setnamedrangename,-range)

Creating multiple named ranges in multiple sheets same spreadsheet

```
function myFunck() {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges().map(r => [r.getName(), r.getRange().getA1Notation()])).replace(/],/g, '],\n'));
  const shts = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const name = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  shts.forEach((n, i) => ss.setNamedRange(name[i],ss.getSheetByName(shts[1]).getRange("A1:J10")))
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges().map(r => [r.getName(), r.getRange().getA1Notation()])).replace(/],/g, '],\n'));
}

Execution log
4:58:05 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:58:05 PM  Info    []
4:58:05 PM  Info    [["name1","A1:J10"],
["name3","A1:J10"],
["name2","A1:J10"]]
4:58:07 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper this really helped! I realized that the problem was that I needed to set the named range for the sheet and then I could set the specific range in the script for the exact range I wanted to name. Also I realized the problem was a syntax error on the sheets side. The name I was using for the range was not accepted for named ranges. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a named range to the copied sheet by `templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName("F"+sheetName);` in your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Traditional Sheet");
  var sheetName = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();

  // I modified the below script.
  var nameOfNamedRange = "sampleName"; // Please set the name of the named range you want.
  var rangeOfNamedRange = "A1"; // Please set the range the named range you want as A1Notation.

  var copiedSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName("F" + sheetName);
  ss.setNamedRange(nameOfNamedRange, copiedSheet.getRange(rangeOfNamedRange));
}
```

- The method "copyTo" of Class Sheet returns the Class Sheet object of the copied sheet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) I thought that this could be used.
- By this modification, in this sample, a named range of "sampleName" is created to "A1" on the copied sheet.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))